# Google api 403 but works on 1 of my accounts

Tags: google-api, google-forms

I have two Google APIs with OAuth 2.0 credentials. One works perfectly, but the other does not. I've followed the same procedure for both, but I receive an error. Can anyone assist in enabling the API key? I have already done this

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl8Tf.png)